# when is it safe to call popBackStack

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

I am getting the dreaded `java.lang.IllegalStateException` Can not perform this action after `onSaveInstanceState` exception.

I am trying to pop the top fragment off the backstack. I thought it was safe to do this after the activity has resumed, but the following stacktrace (redacted) shows otherwise:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack (Unknown Source)
x.MainActivity$2$1.apply (Unknown Source)
x.MainActivity.onResume (Unknown Source)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume (Instrumentation.java:1249)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

So, my question is, when is it safe to pop the topmost fragment from the backstack, and how do I detect that it is safe?

Comment: Have look [this](https://medium.com/@bendaniel10/a-possible-way-to-safely-perform-fragment-transactions-after-activity-onsaveinstancestate-651d4bcb410b)

Answer (score 0):

The only time it is safe to call it is after onPostResume.

You can either use a flag to skip calls to it after onPause and before onPostResume, or you can keep a queue of actions that you execute in onPostResume.